# Java does not find symbols StdIn and StdOut

Tags: java

I am having Java compilation issues. Although I have configured my classpath properly as seen here...

```
yan@Y9Acer:~$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/local/lift/lib/stdlib.jar:/usr/local/lift/lib/introcs.jar:/usr/local/lift/lib/algs4.jar
```

I still get the following StdIn and StdOut errors when building indicating that the symbols weren't found. But these would be found in the stdlib.jar file listed above, so I don't know why this is happening. Does anyone know why this is? I've looked for hours and gotten nowhere.

```
yan@Y9Acer:~$ javac-algs4 coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java
coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        int n = StdIn.readInt();                 // number of pages
                ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class Markov
coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        StdIn.readInt();                         // ignore integer required by input format
        ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class Markov
coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                p[i][j] = StdIn.readDouble();
                          ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class Markov
coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
            StdOut.printf("%8.5f", rank[i]);
            ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class Markov
coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        StdOut.println();
        ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class Markov
coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        StdOut.println();
        ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class Markov
coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
            StdOut.printf("%2d  %5.3f\n", i, rank[i]);
            ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class Markov
7 errors
```

And here is my code, so you can see

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class Markov {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);  // number of iterations
            int n = StdIn.readInt();                 // number of pages
            StdIn.readInt();                         // ignore integer required by input format


            // Read p[][] from StdIn.
            double[][] p
                    = new double[n][n];         // p[i][j] = prob. surfer moves from page i to page j
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    p[i][j] = StdIn.readDouble();

            // Use the power method to compute page ranks.
            double[] rank = new double[n];
            rank[0] = 1.0;
            for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {

                // Compute effect of next move on page ranks.
                double[] newRank = new double[n];
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    //  New rank of page j is dot product of old ranks and column j of p[][].
                    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                        newRank[j] += rank[k] * p[k][j];
                }

                // Update page ranks.
                rank = newRank;
            }

            // print page ranks
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                StdOut.printf("%8.5f", rank[i]);
            }
            StdOut.println();

            StdOut.println();
            // print page ranks
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                StdOut.printf("%2d  %5.3f\n", i, rank[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone? I don't think this is a difficult question for an experienced Java guy.

Comment: `StdIn` and `StdOut` are not standard class names.  You'll need to show us the code.  Where do they come from?

Comment: Added code -- I don't know why the code should matter. My point is that StdOut and StdIn are in my provided stdlib.jar that I added to the classpath ... yet I'm still getting errors!

Comment: Well, I don't see an `import` for `StdIn`.

Comment: Do I need to when it's in the classpath already?

Comment: Yup.  ..........

Comment: That's weird -- I just copied the code from here

https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/16pagerank/Markov.java.html

Is there a mistake they made then?

Comment: Yes, only classes from `java.lang` are imported automatically.  All others must have an explicit import.  (Actually that's not quite true, if the class *source files* are in the same package and in the same compilation path, you don't need it.  But you have Jar files, not source files.  Sounds like you're the victim of somebody's personal project that they just all compiled into one program.)

Comment: It's just particularly egregious that this is a course website and they have simple errors like this.

Comment: Yes it is.  Also I don't like these special `StdIn` and other classes they made.  You'd do better to just learn the standard API.

Comment: So that didn't help -- I STILL get the same issue after adding the import lines.

Comment: The class you linked to had no package.  Are you sure the package you used there is correct?

Comment: yes I am. They said to just add algs4.jar, stdlib.jar, and introcs.jar to my classpath.

Comment: Try adding these jars explicitely to your classpath when compiling. Thus, `javac -cp /usr/local/lift/lib/* coursera/java-stuff/markov/Markov.java` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that before and that works. Why is adding them to the classpath NOT working is my question.

Comment: Oh jesus...it's because I set my CLASSPATH in .bashrc with `CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LIFT_LIB}/stdlib.jar:${LIFT_LIB}/introcs.jar:${LIFT_LIB}/algs4.jar"` instead of
`export CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LIFT_LIB}/stdlib.jar:${LIFT_LIB}/introcs.jar:${LIFT_LIB}/algs4.jar"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either work like it’s 1999 and manually add JAR files to classpath, or you can recognize it’s 2019, and use a build tool like Maven or Gradle to do that for you. The `algs4` JAR is available on BinTray. https://github.com/kevin-wayne/algs4/blob/master/README.md.

I’ve taken this course and used Gradle to build the code. Once you set up the project, you can focus on solving the real problems, and not manipulating classpath. I also started an initiative to better organize the source code for `algs4` (currently one flat structure due to historical reasons) but didn’t get time to finish it.

Answer (score 1):

The command javac-introcs is for use with the book *Introduction to Computer Science: An Interdisciplinary Approach*. The command javac-algs4 is for use with the book *Algorithms, 4e*. The former uses the default package, so no import statement are required; the latter used a named package and import statements are required. So, in your case, use javac-introcs and everything should work.

There is no need to set the CLASSPATH environment variable when using either command.

Comment: Thanks -- and this really should be included on the Princeton course webpage too.

Comment: Also my project folder has subdirectories `.lift` and `.idea`, where the relevant jars (stdlib, algs4, introcs, etc) are in the `.lift/`. Yet they never get picked up when compiling in java, whether by IntelliJ or command line.

It would be great to see images of how to get this going in IntelliJ as well...

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by putting

`# this must match the install directory 
LIFT_LIB="/usr/local/lift/lib"`

`export CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LIFT_LIB}/stdlib.jar:${LIFT_LIB}/introcs.jar:${LIFT_LIB}/algs4.jar"`
in my `.bashrc` file. The reason it didn't work because was because I didn't use `export` command in my `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is an unfair criticism of the course.  The instructions for installing the simplified programming environment (https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/) walk you through the steps, and work correctly, at least in the Linux section.

It appears that @Glassjawed failed to use the javac-introcs & java-introcs commands which are enabled when lift is installed.

Comment: Ok but the fact remains that one may want to use java and javac while adding files to the classpath instead of java-algs4.

Comment: Especially if building in IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Comment: Agreed.  There are always multiple ways to do things. You can use add the classpath, you can use -cp on the command line, or you can use java-introcs.  Either of the three works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following the course  "Computer science an Interdiciplinary approach" having this issue:

- in the book site: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/ they provide a .jar file, that you can add as a dependency of you project  (in intelliJ Idea, you click right on your top project folder  select "Open module settings", then  "Modules" there  you add a dependency. with the plus sign and you select the .jar file they provide.

That should help the IDE to find the class when you use it in your code without any import statement.

If you need to run something on the terminal and the program makes reference one of the classes they provide, you need to add the option `-classpath`. including the .jar file, for example, say you want to run  `RandomSeq`  from the examples in the book:

`java -classpath yourPathToTheCompiledJavaCompiledFiles:yourPathToTheJarFile/stdlib.jar RandomSeq 10`

Note that the `:` on this is a separator, in mac is like this, in other operating systems may be a differen character, and the `stdlib.jar` is the name of the .jar file